# toolbar inside fragment overlaps fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have an AppCompatActivity in which I have a toolbar and a google map fragment. This is made in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarFindRoutes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


</fragment>
```

However, my toolbar is on top of my fragment view. I want to have the fragment beneath the toolbar, but as I understand, I need to have the fragment as the root element in XML. This means I can't have e.g. a RelativeLayout as root, and just declare fragment below toolbar.

Comment: You should put it inside `Frame Layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarFindRoutes"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.robo.movie.movieapp.Movies.ui.MovieListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```